# Cordova/Phonegap + Angular: promise not resolving until next digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, promise

I'm using Angular + JQMobile inside a Cordova mobile app, and I'm having some difficulty with promises.  I have a cordovaReady service that returns a promise and I'm looking to hide a splashscreen (no lectures please) when the promise is resolved.  The trick comes when I try to use an if-then condition to resolve the promises at different times.  My code:

```
app.factory('cordovaReady', function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return {
        ready: function() {
                    document.addEventListener(
                        "deviceready",
                        function () {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        },
                        false
                    );
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
    }
});

app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'TagTemplates', 'cordovaReady', function($scope, $location, TagTemplates, cordovaReady) {
 // If there is a user logged in, --fire camera-- and go to tag template

  if ($scope.currentUser) {
    // fire camera here, make sure cordova is ready first.
    // alert('found user');
    var promise = cordovaReady.ready();
    promise.then(function() {
      // alert('about to capture');
      console.log('firing capture');
      $scope.captureImage();
      navigator.splashscreen.hide(); // this one fires.
    });

    console.log($scope.currentUser);
    $scope.templates = $scope.currentUser.attributes.templates[0];
    $scope.$apply();
    $location.url("/#main");

  } else {
    var promise = cordovaReady.ready();
    promise.then(function() {
      alert('no user logged in, hide splashscreen');
      navigator.splashscreen.hide(); // this one does not.
      $scope.$apply(); // even with this.
    });
  }
}
```

In the case of an existing user, the splashscreen is hidden as desired, I thought because of scope updates that happen within this if statement.  However, in the event of no existing user, the splashscreen does not fire until the next digest cycle (clicking on a button or link in my app).  I verified this with the alert.

I've tried all manner of scope apply, include variants of setTimeout with 0 delay, etc.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Convert the cordova promise to a `$q` promise. Those hook on Angular's digest cycle.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the code that handles the promise `cordovaReady.ready()`. Could just be that the promise isn't resolved properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Just added the cordovaReady code.  Also, you'll notice this stuff is running inside a module.run snippet.

Comment: I'm running into the same issues, any updates on this?

Comment: Did you try wrapping `deferred.resolve` in `$rootScope.$apply`?